# Common Log File System API's RegisterManageableLogClient() and "access is denied" error

Tags: c++, winapi, clfs

I am trying to use Microsoft's Common Log File System (CLFS) API. My code looks like this.

```
CLFS_MGMT_POLICY log_policy;
CLFS_INFORMATION log_info;
ULONG info_size = sizeof (log_info);
ULONGLONG desired_size;
ULONGLONG resulting_size;

data->log_handle = CreateLogFile (
    helpers::towstring (data->log_name).c_str (), GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, 0,
    OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE);

if (data->log_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    loglog_win32_error (LOG4CPLUS_TEXT ("CreateLogFile()"));
    goto error;
}

if (! RegisterManageableLogClient (data->log_handle, 0))
{
    loglog_win32_error (LOG4CPLUS_TEXT ("RegisterManageableLogClient()"));
    goto error;
}
```

The `CreateLogFile()` function executes fine and I can even see a `.blf` file appear on file system. But `RegisterManageableLogClient()` returns with error and `GetLastError()` returns value `5` which is "Access is denied." This code is nearly identical to [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I cannot figure out why is the call to `RegisterManageableLogClient()` failing.

**UPDATE:**

The problem was missing `GENERIC_READ` for `CreateLogFile()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was missing `GENERIC_READ` for `CreateLogFile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interacting with the policy, I guess you need Administrative credentials to perform the registration. This is why you get Access_denied.

Comment: Nope, I run this as Administrator.

Comment: ACCESS_DENIED could mean that the thing is still in use (http://wikiencyclopedia.net/4.0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/cdf/src/WCF/Log/System/IO/Log/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs/1305376/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs)